# I need help in creating an image background slide show or carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I really need help, i'll be eternally grateful if I could solve this as soon as possible.
I'm only trying it with JavaScript but if you've an idea of its css also I can work with that. And kindly notes its an automatic slideshow.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
/* i dont have a css code, if you suggest i add it kindly reply */
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img1.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img2.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img3.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img4.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img5.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img6.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img7.jpeg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img8.jpeg">
```

**strong text**

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp, you could see these 2!